# what does this npgsql Time datatype documentation mean?

Tags: npgsql

We are considering PostgreSQL because of its adherence to ISO 8601 3.5.2, specifically in regard to the standalone (uncombined) Time datatype (e.g. 18:50) as distinct from combined DateTime (Timestamp) type. See the [relevant PostgreSQL 9.2. docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html). The Time of Day datatype is based on the 24-hour clock, disassociated from the calendar, and runs from 00:00 to 24:00.

We have Windows desktops and are contemplating using the npgsql provider for .NET. But I am being thrown by the [documentation of the npgsql provider](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/) for **npgsqlTime** type; the **Hours** instance property reads as follows:

> Gets the number of whole hours held in the instance. Note that the
>   time 24:00:00 can be stored for roundtrip compatibility. *Any
>   calculations on such a value will normalised [sic] it to 00:00:00*. [my emphasis]

"Such a value" refers to "24:00:00".   Do I understand this documentation correctly, that if one were to create two instances of **npgsqlTime** as follows:

```
    NpgsqlTime midnightTonight = new NpgsqlTime(24,0,0);
    NpgsqlTime midnightThisMorning = new NpgsqlTime(0,0,0);
```

and then invoke the Subtract method:

```
    midnightTonight.Subtract(midnightThisMorning);
```

*midnightTonight* will be normalized (silently by the provider) to 00:00, and the result of the subtraction method will be an interval not of 24 hours but of 0 hours?

Or that if we instantiated two Times so:

```
   NpgsqlTime midnightTonight = new NpgsqlTime(24,0,0);
    NpgsqlTime lateAfternoon = new NpgsqlTime(16,0,0);
```

and then subtracted:

```
    midnightTonight.Subtract(lateAfternoon);
```

we would get an interval of 16 hours rather than 8?

EDIT: Now that PostgreSQL and Npgsql are both installed and I can test, it seems the silent "normalisation" of 24:00 to 00:00 does not occur on Subtract() but it does occur on Add().

EDIT: So Subtract() is OK.  We want the answer to be 8, and it is 8.

I am happy that it does not occur on Subtract() and I wish it did not occur by default on Add(), especially since there is a Normalize() method in the public API.

Comment: Hi, Tim. Would you mind to create a bug report about that? I have to check this code to see how I can fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Francisco Junior: hello.  For my purposes, the desired behavior is that the normalisation does not occur automatically. So Subtract() is good.  Did you want to remove the automatic normalisation from Add() method? Or do you want simply to clarify the documentation and leave the behavior as it is?

Comment: I'll try to contact the original developer of this code and ask him to clarify this. I'm inclined to have both methods working consistently and then update the documentation to reflect that.